# Rest api / json error while using it with react chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, chart.js, visualization

Thanks Sergio for your recommended answer. I really like your demonstrated answer, but the problem is that I am still can't able to see the graph due to for each error. The **api here used is using the lambda function of AWS**

1. App.js

   ```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
   import axios from "axios";

   import Chart from "./chart";

   class App extends Component {
     constructor() {
       super();

       this.state = {
         labels: [],
         data: []
       };
     }

     componentDidMount() {
       this.getChartData();
     }

     getChartData() {
       Date.prototype.formatMMDDYYYY = () => {
         return (
           this.getDate() + 1 + "/" + this.getMonth() + "/" + this.getFullYear()
         );
       };

      axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.myjson.com/bins/zfpa2') 
        .then(results => {
         results.forEach(packet => {
           this.state.labels.push(new Date(packet.updated).formatMMDDYYYY());
           this.state.data.push(parseFloat(packet.users));
         });
          this.setState({ data, labels })
       })
        .catch(error => {
         console.log(error);
       })
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <div>
           <Chart labels={this.state.labels} data={this.state.data} />
         </div>
       );
     }
   }

    export default App;
   ```
2. chart.js

   import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';

   ```
    class Chart extends Component {
    render() {
     const chartData = {
     labels: this.props.labels,
     datasets: [
               {
                 data: this.props.data,
                 backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
               }
             ]
           }
     return (
        <div className="chart">
            <Bar 
               data={chartData}
               options={{
                   title: {
                       display: true,
                       text: 'Largest cities in Delhi',
                       fontSize: 25
                   },
                   legend: {
                       display: true,
                       position: 'right'
                   }
               }}
           />
       </div>
      );
     }
    }

    export default Chart;
   ```
3. Package.json

   ```
      {
        "name": "apicharts",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "private": true,
        "dependencies": {
          "axios": "^0.18.0",
          "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
          "jquery": "^3.3.1",
          "react": "^16.8.2",
          "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
          "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
          "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
          "react-vis": "^1.11.6"
        },
        "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
        },
       "eslintConfig": {
       "extends": "react-app"
        },
       "browserslist": [
       ">0.2%",
       "not dead",
       "not ie <= 11",
       "not op_mini all"
        ]
      }
   ```

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Do **NOT** modify state directly. Always use [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

```
// BAD
results.forEach(packet => {
  this.state.labels.push(new Date(packet.updated).formatMMDDYYYY());
  this.state.data.push(parseFloat(packet.users));
});

// GOOD
const labels = [];
const data = [];

results.forEach(packet => {
  labels.push(new Date(packet.updated).formatMMDDYYYY());
  data.push(parseFloat(packet.users));
});

this.setState({ data, labels });
```

When you modify state directly the component never re-renders, meaning `Chart` never re-renders with the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

First: If you want to modify the state of a component, you must do it using the [`this.setState({...})`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) React function, if you do not do it in this way, react will not fire again the render function. So you need to change how you load data:

```
    const labels = [];
    const data = [];
    results.forEach(packet => {
      labels.push(new Date(packet.updated).formatMMDDYYYY());
      data.push(parseFloat(packet.users));
    });
    this.setState({
     labels,
     data
    })
```

Now remember the `constructor` just is fired once the component is going to be mounted so if you set the state of `chart.js` with the values in the props, when the parent component fired the `setState` function your data is not going to be updated. So here we need to remove the following from the `constructor`:

```
chartData: {
    labels: props.labels,
    datasets: [
                {
                  data: props.data,
                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                 }
              ]
 }
```

and added to the `render` function like:

```
const chartData = {
        labels: props.labels,
        datasets: [
                    {
                      data: props.data,
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                     }
                  ]
     }
```

Finally send the data you recently created

```
<Bar 
  data={chartData}
  options={{
      title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Largest cities in Delhi',
          fontSize: 25
      },
      legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'right'
      }
  }}
/>
```

Besides, as you are using `React`, you should not use jQuery. If you just use it for loading data you can use other alternatives like [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to fetch the data :)

**EDIT**

`Date` prototype is readonly so you should create a new function to format it in `App.js`:

```
getFormatDate = (date) => {
    return (
      date.getDate() + 1 + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getFullYear()
    );
  }
```

Modify your `getChartData` with the following code to solve the issue:

```
getChartData() {
   axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.myjson.com/bins/zfpa2') 
     .then(({ data }) => {
       const labels = [];
       const dataArray = [];
       data.forEach(packet => {
        labels.push(this.getFormatDate(new Date(packet.updated)));
        dataArray.push(parseFloat(packet.users));
      });
       this.setState({ data : dataArray, labels })
    })
     .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Hi Sergio, I have really admire your post but can you help me with the problem again which I am facing that is I couldn't able to show the graph. I have updated the question from your recommendation. Would really looking forward for your reply.

Comment: Hi @NikhilVaidyar, could you add the `package.json` of your project please ?

Comment: Hi @SergioEscudero, I have added package.json on above question. You can check it out now.